# assign a model's attribute through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails and working on a rails app and I'm stuck pondering this issue.

I have three models

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :name, :issn, :category, :user_products_attributes

    validates_presence_of :name, :issn, :category
    validates_numericality_of :issn, :message => "has to be a number"

    has_many :user_products
    has_many :users, :through => :user_products

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_products

end




class UserProduct < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :price, :category

  validates_presence_of :price, :category
  validates_numericality_of :price, :message => "has to be a number"

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product

end

class user < ActiveRecord::Base

  # devise authentication here

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_many :user_products, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :products, :through => :user_products

end
```

Product controller

def new

```
@product = product.new

@product.user_products.build 

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @product }
end
```

end

So the question is this: I want the user to enter the info for the product in the form but it also involves putting in the price of the product which exists in a different model/table (user_product) that is associated with product. How can I do this? You can see that my form_for uses @product.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
    <div class="span8">

       <div id="listBoxWrapper">          
        <fieldset>

         <%= form_for(@product, :html => { :class => "form-inline" }, :style => "margin-bottom: 60px" ) do |f| %>


            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="Category">Category</label>
              <div class="controls">

                <%= f.text_field :category, :class => 'input-xlarge', :id => "Category" %>       

              </div>
            </div>

           <div class="control-group" style="display: inline-table;">
           <label class="control-label" for="First Name">Price($/Month)</label>
             <div class="controls">
              <%= product.fields_for :user_products do |p| %>
                <%= p.text_field :price, :class => 'input-xlarge input-name' %>    
                <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I followed ur steps and the railscast tutorials. I have edited the code above...now I get an "unknown attribute: book_id" error...I seem to think I have the naming convention for my user_products wrong...thanks!

Comment: sorry I meant product_id...I think I have it working now...I just added a product_id to my user_products table...

Comment: everything works fine...many thanks!!....I'm however rethinking the way I set up all my models..might not be the best way...if u care, I can explain and maybe you can offer a better way. Thanks again

Comment: ya why not... lets see that :)

Comment: ok cool...I will type up something and send in about an hour...I may need to open up another discussion. thanks again

Comment: @SamironPaul I have added more description above...pls let me know your thoughts...thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey!! Great but would u pls open a new discussion regarding with the last part? this thread is getting longer. And might be confusing to visitors.

Comment: new post is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235905/setup-models-associations-in-rails-3...thanks

Comment: when a user is adding a product, how do I ensure that the current user id is added to the user_product table?...at the moment only the product id is added to the user_product table. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be kind of following

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |product| %>
  <%= product.text_field :name, :class => 'input-xlarge input-name' %>
  <%= product.fields_for :user_products do |user_product| %>
      <%= user_product.text_field :price, :class => 'input-xlarge input-name' %>
```

and you need to build your `user_products` for the `@product` in your controller. Like

```
@product.user_products.build
```

and your `Product` model should have the following

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_products
```

This will make it realized that `user_products` values might come while saving a product entity.

**Edit:**

Just explaining the skeleton of nested form

```
form_for(@object) do |object_form_builder|
       # call any field generator helper function by object_form_builder like
       object_form_builder.text_field
       object_form_builder.check_box
       # so on...

       #Now for nested forms get the nested objects from the builder like
       object_form_builder.fields_for :nested_objects do |nested_object_builder|
             #generate the fields for this with nested_object_builder. Like
             nested_object_builder.text_field
             # so on...
       end
 end
```

yes its always convenient to use short names for object builders like you usually use `f` for `form_builder`.

Comment: ok I'm working on using your solution. But I'm getting an error that says product in product.fields_for is an undefined local variable or method...also what is the purpose of using build? thanks

Comment: Can you paste your `form` code. Because if `product.text_field` can run, there is no reason for `product.fields_for` to fail. `build` is the mechanism to tell the `@product` that `i may need to generate fields for these entities also`. Look when you want to generate the form of a `@product` only, you build the product by `Product.new`. But here you need the fields for `@product.user_products` also. So you have to build that.

Comment: I fixed the errors. The page loads, but the text_field for the price doesnt show.

Comment: I'd try to keep your block variables something like `f` or something simple in your forms, using `product` and `user_product` (or something that would resemble an instance of an model) gets kind of confusing. And in his posted update, you can see he used `product.fields_for` instead of `f.fields_for`.

Comment: @justcode you'll need to "build" a `user_product` if you don't have one already existing, else it won't show anything. You can do this in your controller after you have setup Product, `@product.user_products.build`

Comment: Please add the `build` line in your controller code and see if it render the form fields.

Comment: I've added it to the create method in the product controller...but it still doesnt show

Comment: From your update i can see that you used like, `form_for(@product) .. .. |f|` but again `product.fields_for`. It should be `f.fields_for`. Can u pls make sure that the form you have given at the last part of your question is exactly what u have in your view?

Comment: yea I have changed all that...that's why the page loads...but the price field doesnt show up..

Comment: ok Just share your `controller method`, Update the `view` code. Hope you added `acccept_nested_attributes_for` in your models. You are using rails 3 right? Your tags are saying that.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 this is exactly you need to do. See if you can find any difference.