# add current user to model table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I add the current user to the user_product table when saving a user's product.

I looked at some info online that shows that I can pass in a parameter to the build method, but this doesnt work. The error message is this "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user_id"

Product controller:

def new

```
@product = Product.new

@product.user_products.build(:user_id => current_user)

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @product }
end
```

end

My models are: `Product`, `User`, `User_Product`

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

```
    attr_accessible :name, :issn, :category, :user_products_attributes

    validates_presence_of :name, :issn, :category
    validates_numericality_of :issn, :message => "has to be a number"

    has_many :user_products
    has_many :users, :through => :user_products

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_products

end




class UserProduct < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :price

  validates_presence_of :price
  validates_numericality_of :price, :message => "has to be a number"

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product

end

class user < ActiveRecord::Base

  # devise authentication here

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_many :user_products, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :products, :through => :user_products

end
```

Comment: @samironpaul....hey is the post

Comment: Your question is a little vague, can you explain what you mean by "setup these models efficiently"?

Comment: @Beerlington I'm simply asking for the best way to set up the models

Comment: not exactly an answer to this question, but have you looked at spree? https://github.com/spree/spree, which is a great RoR based open source application for cart and checkout

Comment: I've looked at it...i plan to use it for the cart and checkout....but this question is just for meet to correctly setup the associations between my models...thanks again

Comment: @Beerlington, what should I do to make the post clearer? I figured out a few things and streamlined my question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

```
Product
  has_many :preferences
  has_many :users, :through => preferences
  has_one :product_photo # if 1 per product

User
  has_many :preferences
  has_many :products, :through => :preferences

Preference
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product

ProductPhoto
  belongs_to :product
```

Whatever you do, make sure you pay attention to capitalization and pluralization as rails is pretty picky about that.  If you don't get rails conventions right, the code will not work (and worse you will start writing hacks to get around the perceived 'problem'), for instance User_Product should be UserProduct (or Preference in my answer) not User_Product - for the class definition model name (references to it use lower case and underscore though).

Comment: @MichaelDurrant...the photo(s) actually should belong to a user's listing (the Preference model)...